# Show message when dropdown is selected on press

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a questionaire written in PHP, jQuery and Boostrap. Users must select some of the answers by either a checkbox or dropdown menu. When they press on the next button (Arrow) then the system must check if they have selected a option. If not, a simple message apears.

```
    <label for="vraag1">Ik ben een...</label>
    <select name="vraag1" class="">
    <option value="">-- kies een antwoord --</option>
    <option value="antw1"<?php echo $_POST['vraag1'] == "antw1" ? " selected" : ""; ?>>Jongen</option>
    <option value="antw2"<?php echo $_POST['vraag1'] == "antw2" ? " selected" : ""; ?>>Meisje</option>
    </select>
```

**Button**

```
<div class="pageNext span1"><a href="#stap3" data-toggle="tab" class="tabber"><img id="next_stap3" src="<?php echo BASEURL; ?>img/arrow-right.png" alt="Volgende pagina" title="Volgende pagina" /></a></div>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( function(){                                                          // Dom ready
    $( "#id-of-your-button" ).click( function(){                        // Trigger click in button
        if( ( $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).length === 0 ) ||     // We have a checkox checked
            ( $( "select" ).val() === "" ) )                            // We have selected an option in the select?
        {
            $( "body" ).prepend( "Dude you must select something!" )    // Insert message
            return false;                                               // Prevent default behavior and bubbling in the button
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very good :) I implemented it into my script. Thank you. But where do I put the else? Cause if i selected the checkbox it must advance :)

Comment: No matter what I try, it is stuck at the first message. What i have is this:

$(function(){
$("#stap_4").click( function(){
            if( ( $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).length === 0 ) || ( $( "select" ).val() === "" ) ) 
            {
                $( "body" ).prepend( "Not checked" )
                return false;                                           
            }
      else
      {
       $( "body" ).prepend( "Checked, proceed" )
                return true;    
      }
      } );